# Python: Multiplying a list of vectors by a list of matrices as a single matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a list of 100 `N-dimensional` vectors and a list of `100 MxN` matrices. So you can think of the two data structures as a `100xN` list (or numpy array) and a `100xMxN` list (or numpy array).

What I want to do is take the dot product of each vector and its corresponding matrix, such that the output should be `100 M-dimensional` matrices (i.e. a `100xM` list or numpy array).

However, I'm not really sure how to do this. I don't want to do it iteratively, for obvious reasons about efficiency. I also know it's not basic matrix multiplication. I think I might want to use `np.einsum`, but I'm not overly familiar with it.

Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,ikj->ik',a,b)
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: M,N = 3,4

In [43]: a = np.random.rand(100,N)

In [44]: b = np.random.rand(100,M,N)

In [45]: np.einsum('ij,ikj->ik',a,b).shape
Out[45]: (100, 3)
```

You can also use `np.matmul` or `@` operator (Python 3.x) though it seems marginally slower than `einsum` -

```
np.matmul(a[:,None],b.swapaxes(1,2))[:,0]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I recommend [this page] (http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) for anyone unsure of why this solution works. It's pretty clear now.